# Не удаляется класс active JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

У меня есть меню с выпадающим списком. Задача очень простая и состоит в том, чтобы при клике на элемент меню открывался дополнительный список.

HTML:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.main-menu li a {
    color: #000;
}
.sub {
    display: none;
}
.main-menu li a.active + .sub {
    display: block;
}
```

Script:

```
$('.main-menu > li > a').click(function () {
    $('.main-menu > li > a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Все вроде бы работает отлично, но при повторном клике не удаляется класс `active` и не закрывается выпадающий список. Не могу понять, где ошибка?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r14nep26/)

Comment: А почему класс должен удаляться если вы его удаляете и тут же ставите снова?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует добавить условие:

```
$('.main-menu > li > a').click(function () {
if( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
}                  
else {
     $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте просто:

```
$('.main-menu > li > a').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```